# While writing packets to interface using raw socket, process is not receiving these packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I'm writing the following packet on eth3 port using raw sockets:

```
------------------
ETHERNET HEADER
------------------
+ IP HEADER
------------------
+UDP HEADER
------------------
+Payload
------------------
```

If I observe the packets coming out of the eth3 interface using wireshark, I can see the packets I'm sending, but the process that is supposed to receive these packets, which is reading from eth3 is somehow not receiving those packets.

If I send the same packet on eth3, externally using another computer and writing to it's eth3 interface and connecting it to the former machine via lan, the process seems to receive those packets.

I'm suspecting that there is some problem when I'm trying to send packets internally, that is via a process on the same machine.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Are you sending the packets out to the network, and trying to read the same packets on the same interface you are using to send them?

Comment: I'm writing the packets on eth3 interface and the ethernet header contains correct destination MAC address. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to simulate that the packet is coming from an external entity by writing it to eth3 using a raw socket.

Comment: Basically, what I mean to say is that the destination MAC address in the packet is of the eth3 interface itself.

Comment: Don't think it's going to work. Basically what's happening is Wireshark capturing all packets, incoming *and* outgoing. It uses promiscuous socket mode for that. For normal sockets there's no way to see outgoing packets at all, and outgoing packets never become incoming because normal network interfaces just don't do that. There's the loopback interface that is specifically designed to handle this situation, why not use it?

Comment: So what this essentially means is that the packets I'm writing are outbound packets and will not be received by the process that is trying to read that? According to my understanding, since the destination MAC in the Ethernet header is of eth3 itself, it should be received as inbound traffic by eth3. What is your view on this n.m.??

Comment: Why do you think it should be received? As in, which mechanisms are responsible for that?

Comment: According to my understanding, the raw socket is writing on the eth3 interface which has no way of distinguishing where the packet contents are coming from. It should receive the packet as inbound as the destination MAC is the same as its MAC address. I'm not sure on this though.

Answer (score 0):

your process may filter the message according to it's packet type (it may / may not process packet with type=3).

Here's the list of packet types (copied from file `if_packet.h`):

```
#define PACKET_HOST         0       /* To us        */
#define PACKET_BROADCAST    1       /* To all       */
#define PACKET_MULTICAST    2       /* To group     */
#define PACKET_OTHERHOST    3       /* To someone else  */
#define PACKET_OUTGOING     4       /* Outgoing of any type */
#define PACKET_LOOPBACK     5       /* MC/BRD frame looped back */
#define PACKET_USER         6       /* To user space    */
#define PACKET_KERNEL       7       /* To kernel space  */
```